# Reminders application - Trigger

Tags: sqlite, lazarus, freepascal

I new with lazarus, and I was wondering if one of you could give a solution to a barrier I have come across.

My application is set out into frames. There is a reminders frame that allows you to create a reminder. This is my code in that frame.

```
reminder_frame.pas:


   unit reminder_frame;

    {$mode objfpc}{$H+}

    interface

    uses
      Classes, SysUtils, sqlite3conn, sqldb, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, StdCtrls,
      Buttons, ExtCtrls, ExtDlgs, dialogs;

    type

      { TReminderFrame }

      TReminderFrame = class(TFrame)
        Button1: TButton;
        btnCalendar: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        createdb: TButton;
        CalendarDialog1: TCalendarDialog;
        DescriptionMemo: TMemo;
        Image2: TImage;
        NameEdit: TEdit;
        HoursEdit: TEdit;
        Label2: TLabel;
        MinsEdit: TEdit;
        editDate: TEdit;
        Image1: TImage;
        Label1: TLabel;
        SQLiteConnection: TSQLite3Connection;
        SQLQuery: TSQLQuery;
        SQLTransaction: TSQLTransaction;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure btnCalendarClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure createdbClick(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { private declarations }
      public
        { public declarations }
      end;

    implementation

    {$R *.lfm}

    { TReminderFrame }

    uses dashboard_unit;

    procedure TReminderFrame.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if NameEdit.Text = '' then
      begin
        showmessage('Name required.');
      end else
      if editDate.Text = '' then
      begin
        showmessage('Date required.');
      end else
      if HoursEdit.Text = '' then
      begin
        showmessage('Hour required.');
      end else
      if MinsEdit.Text = '' then
      begin
        showmessage('Mins required.');
      end else
      if DescriptionMemo.Text = '' then
      begin
        showmessage('Description required.');
      end else
      begin
        SQLTransaction.StartTransaction;
        SQLQuery.SQL.Clear;
        SQLQuery.SQL.Add('select * from reminders where reminder_name = "'+ NameEdit.Text +'"');
        SQLQuery.Open;
        SQLQuery.Edit;
        SQLQuery['reminder_name']:=NameEdit.Text;
        SQLQuery['reminder_date']:=StrToDateTime(editDate.Text+' '+HoursEdit.Text+':'+MinsEdit.Text+':00');
        SQLQuery['reminder_description']:=DescriptionMemo.Text;
        SQLQuery.Post;
        SQLQuery.ApplyUpdates;
        SQLQuery.Close;
        SQLTransaction.Commit;
        SQLTransaction.EndTransaction;
        Form1.showreminders;
        Self.Hide;
        Self.Free;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TReminderFrame.btnCalendarClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if CalendarDialog1.Execute then
      begin
        editDate.Text:=DateTimeToStr(CalendarDialog1.Date);
      end;
    end;

    procedure TReminderFrame.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Self.Hide;
      Self.Free;
    end;

    procedure TReminderFrame.createdbClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      newFile : Boolean;
    begin
      SQLiteConnection.Close; // Ensure the connection is closed when we start

      try
        // Since we're making this database for the first time,
        // check whether the file already exists
        newFile := not FileExists(SQLiteConnection.DatabaseName);

        if newFile then
        begin
          // Create the database and the tables
          try
            SQLiteConnection.Open;
            SQLTransaction.Active := true;

            // Here we're setting up a table named "DATA" in the new database
            SQLiteConnection.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE "reminders"('+
                        ' "id" Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+
                        ' "reminder_name" Char(128) NOT NULL,'+
                        ' "reminder_description" Char(128) NOT NULL,'+
                        ' "reminder_date" DateTime NOT NULL);');

            // Creating an index based upon id in the DATA Table
            // SQLiteConnection.ExecuteDirect('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Data_id_idx" ON "DATA"( "id" );');

            SQLTransaction.Commit;

            ShowMessage('Succesfully created database.');
          except
            ShowMessage('Unable to Create new Database');
          end;
        end;
      except
        ShowMessage('Unable to check if database file exists');
      end;
     end;

    end.
```

I have a database (SQLite3) with the following DATA:

```
    SQLiteConnection.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE "reminders"('+
                ' "id" Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+
                ' "reminder_name" Char(128) NOT NULL,'+
                ' "reminder_description" Char(128) NOT NULL,'+
                ' "reminder_date" DateTime NOT NULL);');
```

And I have a TStringGrid on my main form that lists all of my reminders. I am hoping to put a delete button on soon, but for now I just have to delete my database :/

So, to the problem in hand: How am I to notify the user (me) when a reminder's 'reminder_date' is the real date and time (now).

I am just wanting the following information on a showmessage:

showmessage('You have a reminder! '+ [the due reminder's name] +' is due.' + [the due reminder's description] )

Thank you all!

Want any info? Feel free to ask!

Harrison

Comment: add a ttimer, and check every xxx time.

Answer (score 0):

How a date+time value is stored in the backend DB depends on the RDMS in question and the column type it is defined as.

In Lazarus (and Delphi) code, a TDateTime is handled as a decimal-pointed number:  the part ahead of the decimal point is the "day number" (the number of days that have passed since 30 December 1899) and the part after the point (the "mantissa" or "fractional part") is the time of day.

One way to deal with your problem is to periodically execute a SQL query of the form

```
Select * from reminders where (reminder_date >= :date) and reminder_date < :date + 1)
```

where :date is a parameter which you set as `now`, assuming you want the results for the remainder of the day from the current time.  If your reminders have a resolution of, say, 15 minutes, then in the query results, you need to do your alert for each row in the query results where

```
SqlQuery.FieldByName('reminder_date').AsDateTime - Now <= 1 / (24 * 4)
```

4 because there are 4 fifteen minute periods in an hour.

Comment: You don't seem interested in this answer.  Shall I delete it?